# Oracle RAC RMAN Backup not writing to NFS Share

Tags: oracle, database-administration, nfs, rman

```
run {
    SET nocfau;
    
    ALLOCATE CHANNEL CH0 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '/nfs/datafile/%U_%T';
    ALLOCATE CHANNEL CH1 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '/nfs/datafile/%U_%T';
    ALLOCATE CHANNEL CH2 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '/nfs/datafile/%U_%T';
    ALLOCATE CHANNEL CH3 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '/nfs/datafile/%U_%T';
    
    BACKUP AS COPY INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0 TAG 'INCR_MERGE' DATABASE;
    BACKUP ARCHIVELOG ALL FORMAT '/nfs/archivelogs/%U' NOT BACKED UP 1 TIMES;
    
    RELEASE CHANNEL CH0;
    RELEASE CHANNEL CH1;
    RELEASE CHANNEL CH2;
    RELEASE CHANNEL CH3;
}
```

The above is the `rman script` to run backup for Oracle RAC. I have NFS share that is mounted with following options: ***rw,user,hard,noac,vers=4***

The NFS Server has the following export: `NFSv4,rw,no_root_squash,no_all_squash,secure`

The issue is that nothing gets written to the NFS share. I can create files, copy large files, but when RMAN is run nothing is copied to the NFS share.
The RMAN process runs till it's terminated.

When I do ***nfsiostat -a*** it shows 5 mandatory GETATTR requests.
Does it mean the Oracle datafiles are not being written in NFS share because the file attributes along with file uid/gid is not being successfully retrieved?

Update: tried running the backup on Oracle 19c RAC setup
Get the following RMAN error

```
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on CH0 channel at 08/24/2020 16:59:11
ORA-19504: failed to create file "/home/oracle/nfs/ractest/1178998226/full/datafile/data_D-ORAMS19C_I-1178998226_TS-SYSAUX_FNO-3_rhv8m5mt_20200824"
ORA-17503: ksfdopn:11 Failed to open file /home/oracle/nfs/ractest/1178998226/full/datafile/data_D-ORAMS19C_I-1178998226_TS-SYSAUX_FNO-3_rhv8m5mt_20200824
ORA-17500: ODM err: No such file or directory
```

I ran the rman backup on a local disk they succeed and the datafiles have the group asmadmin. Do backups fail on NFS share becuase the datafile attributes/group information is not being copied to the NFS share?
The oracle user is not part of the asmadmin group.

Comment: What error did you get? Have you tried to trace RMAN using `DEBUG TRACE` options?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov ORA-06515, ORA-19583 But this happens because I press ctrl-c. Apart from that, I don't see any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with Oracle 12.1, Following the oracle support document and applying the patch(20720667) provided has resolved the issue. Here is the [link](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=155728180740647&parent=SrDetailText&sourceId=3-23947083441&id=2094406.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=dwp8pr5g4_119)

Answer (score 0):

Your NFS options are wrong for RMAN. For Oracle RAC, they should be as follows:

```
rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,vers=3,timeo=600
```

These options are required, per Oracle documentation. Also, the use of the "noac" option is specifically a problem for RMAN and should not be used.

Comment: I am running back up to the NFS, not using the NFS as the storage for database datafiles and running the RAC cluster. should I still use the same settings? The odd thing is the backups from the other RAC machine go through without issues.

Comment: Yes, the same settings apply for RMAN backup destinations.